# Drupal 7 form_state[redirect] does not work

Tags: 7, redirection, forms

I am new to Drupal development and I stuck on a problem.
I have got a form which I append to a node. The custom submit method is called correctly, but my redirect does not work. When I press the button I got redirected to the form.
Thank you very much in advance

```
    function ticketGenerator_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
    $nodetype = node_type_get_type($node);
    $nodetype = $nodetype->type;
    if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node) && $nodetype=='event') {
    $node->content['buttonKaufentest'] = drupal_get_form('ticketGenerator_generateform',$node);
    }
    return $node;
```

}

```
    function ticketGenerator_generateform($form, &$form_state,$node){
    $form = array();
    $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
);
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit' ,
    '#value' => 'buttonalter',
    '#submit' => array('ticketGenerator_list_submit')
 );
 return $form;
```

}

```
   function ticketGenerator_list_submit($form,$form_state){
   drupal_set_message('custom submit has been invoked');
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'www.google.de';
   }
```

Comment: As nearly as I can tell, your custom submit function does nothing but set the message and the value of $form_state['redirect']. It does not actually submit the form. You do not get redirected back to the form. You never left it. All that happened is your browser refreshed itself with the message.

Comment: If that is all you want to have happen, add the line `drupal_redirect_form($form_state);` after setting the redirect (and after changing the parameter to pass by reference) and try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `$form_state` in by reference, or the change won't be persisted outside of the function scope:

```
function ticketGenerator_list_submit($form, &$form_state) {
```

Comment: Ahh damn! How couldnt I see it myself?Thank you very much! That fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I was working on old code and didn't spot the missing &.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for Drupal 7 forms. I was setting $form_state[redirect] in the submit handler function and I also did a print_r() to make sure it was there and it was. But it wouldn't redirect. I had to unset the following variables in order for it to work:

```
unset($form_state['rebuild']);
unset($_GET['destination']);
```